# where to call the base class's implementation in derived class?

Tags: java, android

Sometimes,deriving classes should always call through to the base implementation. where should I put the calling statement, before or after the subclass-specific code. For example:

```
boolean foo(T x) {
    super.foo(x);
    ....blabla...; //< derived calss-specific code
    return true;
}
```

OR

```
boolean foo(T x)
{
    ....blabla...; //<  derived calss-specific code
    return super.foo(x);
}
```

How to make a correct decision on different situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on what the superclass method does, and what the subclass method does.

If the work done by the superclass must be done before, put the super call before. If the work done by the superclass must be done after, put the super call after. If some work must be done before the superclass method and some after, then put it in between.

If the order doesn't matter, the usual way is to call the superclass method at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you so much. but I seems difficult for me to make out precisely what the superclass has done.

Comment: @jit - in that case you need to find out. The documentation for the superclass will usually come with examples or guidelines that show how to use it. If not, try to get the source and find out for yourself. Worst case, you are usually safe to call the superclass at the beginning of your derived method just as JB suggests.